# Can we override the Google Sheets UI controls behaviour using Google App Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to have a very granular control on what the users can/can't do. For ex, I want to create a template sheet programmatically where the users can't change the structure (insert/delete rows or columns) but can enter numbers. However, as per this [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/), it seems that this is not possible :

> Change features in Google Apps
>
> The add-ons framework is designed to enhance Google Sheets, Docs, and
>   Forms — not to add limits. Consequently, you can't alter existing
>   features or lock down the Google Apps sharing model.

Is there some work around for this?
Further, is there any event handlers such as

```
OnBeforeAction(), OnAfterAction(), CanProceedWithAction()
```

so that I can write some customization to the behaviors?

Answer (score 0):

You could try protecting the sheet its self, but as an exception, add all the cells.

This should prevent them clicking the "Row" or "Column" numbers/letters to delete or insert rows/columns.

Chris